# How to move a leading substring to the end of string?

Tags: php, string, string-concatenation, substring

How can I cut part of string before some word put on the end of the same string?

For example:

```
$data = '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg,';
```

I want to put all before `4.jpg,` at the end of string like this:

```
$data = '4.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg,1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,';
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I tried str_replace(); and chop();

Answer (score 2):

Here's something you can try.

```
<?php

$data = '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg,';
$cut_name = '4.jpg'; //splice from #4


$data = explode(',', $data);
$cut_from = array_search($cut_name, $data);
array_pop($data);

$removed = array_splice($data, 0, $cut_from);

$data = implode(',', array_merge($data, $removed));

echo $data . ',';
```

Comment: it's nice but 4.jpg,5.jpg,... was only example and every time I will have other file names.

Comment: It should work with any filenames. The `$cut_from` indicates **position**, not the filename.

Comment: but also I don't know which actually position shoult be separator.

Comment: I know only filename, not position

Comment: @MateuszJi I've updated the code. You can specify which `$cut_name = '4.jpg';` to cut from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also some like this:

```
$data = '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg';

function reorder_string($string,$separator){

    $splited = explode($separator,$string);

    //Explanations:
    //$splited[0] = "1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,"
    //$splited[1] = "5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg"
    //$separator = "4.jpg,"

    //finally reorder
    return $separator.$splited[1].",".$splited[0];
}

echo reorder_string($data,"4.jpg,");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too easy with this two-function, one-liner!

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ec0007622869427db465694d9750a5f52891dd2))

```
$data = '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg,';
$new_leader='4.jpg';

echo strstr($data,$new_leader),strstr($data,$new_leader,true);
```

Output:

```
4.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg,1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,
```

*note, *can* break if you change `2.jpg` to `44.jpg` due to unintended substring matching.